# Persistent css rule changes for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to permanently modify a css rule (such that new elements will take on this css rule). It appears that all jquery modifications using css do not persist (Say modifying a background color for future elements does not persist when they are created):

```
$(".red").css("background-color", "blue");
```

See my fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvm0c7m6/

I would like all future elements to now have the new rule created by css, is there a way to do this (with good cross browser support).

Comment: When you say "permanent", it doesn't carry the same weight as it does in the real world of time. The majority of JavaScript is pretty much event driven and just about everything lives within the timespan of a function. or session. And when a browser changes to another page, directory, site,etc., most or all of the JavaScript from the former location is garbage collected. Any changes done to styles directly or indirectly to a stylesheet, style block, or style attribute are temporary. Changes done to a document with an editor is permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You order javascript at execution time to add an inline style to all elements with class 'red', coloring them blue. After that you add new elements to the DOM. They have no knowledge of the earlier command an therefore are not influenced by them.

This solves your problem, as this adds a style rule to the document. This influences all elements and is 'persistent':

```
$( "<style>.red { background: blue; }</style>" ).appendTo( "body" );
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/aLghL2ke/

Note that if you want to run this command multiple times, it would be nice to remove the old style block from your code. This can be done with jQuery too using this command:

```
$( "body style" ).remove();
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/4duxsz0a/

Comment: Thanks, will this ever cause a problem if I do this many times (maximum 100 times, but probably not this many). I suppose what I am saying is does this rewrite the rule, or add another .red style rule onto the stylesheet? I think this is answered by your edit, thanks.

Comment: It adds the rule. That is inefficient, but is not very likely to cause any problems.

Comment: Is there a replace method that would simply replace the rule in head with a new one?

Comment: You are extremely helpful, wish I could upvote more than once. Thanks.